# Cannot fix ERROR:ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, permissions, security, oracle-10g

I have tried almost every solution on the internet however I still cannot fix this problem. I cannot login as sysdba every time I try `SQL>connect /as sysdba` I get the error `ERROR:ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

My account is in ora_dba group. I'm using oracle 10g. I'm new to database so I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you run this on the server that hosts the database and that you have set the `ORACLE_SID` to the one of the database that you want to access. You must run the `orapwd` application. This generates a file that holds the password. Check the documentation for the exact syntax. It depends a bit on the OS on which you host the database.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is it might be a permission problem because when I try to login to sqlplus gui It disappears after I hit enter. I can only use it if I run it as administrator. I'm using windows 10 btw.  Do you think the two problems are related? I was also able to login as sysdba and use the sqlplus gui a while ago but now I'm suddenly facing this problem.

Comment: I do not know Windows 10 and I have no experience with hosting Oracle on Windows. It might be that the user with the 'problem' does not have permission to read the `$ORACLE_HOME//dbs` directory. To logon the way you do you need to have access to the `orapwSID` file.